# Can't .replace style attribute? Works for src, height etc

Tags: javascript

I need javascript to change the background color in the table and tr tags (html generated server side which I can't control)

Here is the html to change

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" id="cphMain_gvStore" style="background-color:#DEBA84;border-color:#DEBA84;border-width:1px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="color:White;background-color:#A55129;font-weight:bold;">
```

Here is my script (based on a working one to change image src)

```
 var tablec2 = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var i=0; i<tablec2.length; i++) {
  var tr = tablec2[i];

   tr.style = tr.style.replace(/A55129$/, '888');
   tr.style = tr.style.replace(/FFF7E7$/, 'F9F9F9');
}
```

Any ideas why this type of script works for changing the height, width and src or an image tag but refuses to change the style tag of this table?

I also used this script to change a td height but for some reason, style doesn't want to cooperate.

This is the script that worked with images:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
var img = images[i];

img.src = img.src.replace(/0-1-1$/, '0-0-1');

   if (img.width == '240' && img.height == '240') {
    img.width = '320';
    img.height = '320';
   }
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use jquery?

Comment: Did you debug `tr.style`? `style` is a special object containing all the element's styles, not the attribute contents - you should use `tr.getAttribute('style')` if you just want to edit the style attribute

Comment: Style is not a string its CssStyleDeclaration object.

Comment: @Mr.GT Why should someone load an entire external library for a task like that?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - so would i do this? 
    `code tr.getAttribute('style').backgroundColor = tr.getAttribute('style').backgroundColor.replace(/A55129$/, '888');`

Answer (score 2):

The style property doesn't map directly onto the style attribute and it is not a string.

Edit `.style.backgroundColor` and `.style.color` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var tablec2 = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i=0; i<tablec2.length; i++) {
var tr = tablec2[i];                    if(colorToHex(tr.style.backgroundColor).toLowerCase() == "#A55129".toLowerCase()){
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "#888";
}
}

function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

    var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
    var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};
```

Comment: so something is preventing it taking effect on my page then... thanks again

Comment: when i pasted the entire source code of my site in jsfiddle it didn't work

Comment: If possible plz share ur jsfiddle link so that I can able to see the problem

Comment: hi, i updated it on the jsfiddle link you gave me, and i think the problem is because the table seems to be nested in another one. i can't change that either due to the fact the page comes from a server that isn't mine.